# Typescript precompile json into variable

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

In a local Webapp where file:// protocol is disallowed for XHR Requests, is it possible to precompile a json file into a variable?

Typescript PseudoCode

```
[JSON("Filename,json"), options]
public myFunc() : void {
     //i can use "options" as a variable here
    console.log(options);
}
```

Expected Javascript output

```
var options = "{jsonfile content}";
function myFunc() {
    console.log(options);
}
```

Is there any library out there, that manages [JSON("Filename,json"), options] this to load the contents of Filename.json into a variable called options during compilation into javascript?

Resume

- Local Application (file://)
- No Ajax allowed (even no jsonp as file:// is completely dissallowed by chrome e.g.)
- Precompiler directive to load local json file into javascript variable
- Any other solution possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not have attributes. However you could quite simply do the following:

```
// file a 
var json = {
    "foo" : "foo's content",
    "bar" : ["some","array"]
}
var jsonContent = JSON.stringify(json);

// file b 
///<reference path="./a.ts"/>
// I think you probably want json not jsonContent
var options = jsonContent; 
function myFunc() {
    console.log(options);
}
```

And then compile file b with the `--out` compiler flag to get one merged javascript file.

Comment: Thx @basarat, but the problem with your solution is the declaration of the json var inside the json file. I'm using this json file elsewhere and need the content to be plain json.

Comment: I would recommend writing a small utility that converts `.json` files into `.ts` files with the shown syntax